# Problemas al llamar un método Board desde un objeto Game

Tags: python, poo

tengo el siguiente problema:

Al llamar al método `game.get_player_coordinates()` desde la clase `Game` en la función `main` -como muestra la imagen- obtengo un lista vacía, pero cuando hago lo mismo pero desde la clase `Board` obtengo la lista de `coordinates`.

1. En este caso obtengo las lista de coordenadas.

```
    from Color import Color
    from Turn import Turn
    from Coordinate import Coordinate

     class Board:
        def __init__(self):
            self.flat: dict = {color: set() for color in Color.colors()}
            self.turn = Turn()
    
        def put(self, target: Coordinate):
            self.flat.get(self.turn.take()).add(target)
    
        def get_color(self, target):
            for color in self.flat.keys():
                if target in self.flat[color]:
                    return color
            return Color.NONE
    
        def get_player_coordinates(self):
            return Board.get_coordinates(lambda target: self.get_color(target) == self.turn.take())
    
        @classmethod
        def get_coordinates(cls, is_equals_color):
            coordinates = []
            for i in range(1, Coordinate.DIMENSION + 1):
                for j in range(1, Coordinate.DIMENSION + 1):
                    coordinate = Coordinate(i, j)
                    if is_equals_color(coordinate):
                        coordinates.append(coordinate)
            return coordinates


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        board = Board()
        board.put(Coordinate(1, 1))
        board.put(Coordinate(1, 2))
        print(board.get_player_coordinates()) # [Coordinate(1, 1), Coordinate(1, 2)]
```

2. En este caso no obtengo la lista. Obtengo una lista vacía.

```
     from Coordinate import Coordinate
     from Board import Board

     class Game:
           def __init__(self):
               self.board = Board()
            
           def put(self, coordinate):
               self.board.put(coordinate)
            
           def get_player_coordinates(self):
               return self.board.get_player_coordinates()
     if __name__ == '__main__':
           game = Game()
           game.put(Coordinate(1, 1))
           game.put(Coordinate(1, 2))
           print(game.get_player_coordinates()) #OBTENGO LISTA VACÍA -> []
```

3. Archivo Color.py

```
    from enum import Enum
    
    
    class Color(Enum):
        XS = "XS"
        OS = "OS"
        NONE = "NONE"
    
        @classmethod
        def colors(cls):
            return list([Color.OS, Color.XS])
```

4. Archivo Coordinate.py

```
 class Coordinate:

        DIMENSION = 3

        def __init__(self, row=0, column=0):
            self.row = row
            self.column = column
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return "Coordinate({},{})".format(self.row, self.column)
    
        def __hash__(self):
            return hash((self.__row, self.__column))
    
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return isinstance(other, Coordinate) and self.row == other.row and self.column == other.column
```

5. Archivo Turn.py

```
from Color import Color
    
    
    class Turn:
        def __init__(self):
            self.__value = 0
    
        def take(self):
            return Color.colors()[self.__value]
    
        def change_to_next_player(self):
            self.__value = (self.__value + 1) % (len(Color.colors()))
```

He probado todo, pero no entiendo por que no funciona.

Comment: Hola Pablo, un par de observaciones; en tu código ejemplo nunca llamas al método `game.get_player_coordinates()` , de hecho no llegas ni ha instanciar `Game`. Supongo que sera un error al crear el ejemplo, porque en ambos casos instancias `Board` y llamas a `board.get_player_coordinates()`.

Comment: Que te retorne una lista vacía posiblemente sea causa de que `if is_equals_color(coordinate)` no se evalue como cierta, es decir que `self.get_color(coordinate) == self.turn.take()` sea falso por alguna razón. Por desgracia faltan componentes para poder reproducir el código y el error como los atributos/metodos `turn` y `get_color` y otras clases como `Coordinate` o `Color`.

Comment: Estimado. Gracias por su apunte. Tiene todo el código disponible. Con respecto a la posible causa de error, tiene razón, pero la cuestión es la siguientes: cuando ejecuto el código desde la clase `Board`, funciona todo perfecto, pero cuando lo hago desde la clases `Game` no obtengo la lista de coordenadas.

Comment: Ok, para reproducir el código te falta el atributo de clase `DIMENSION` y el metodo `clone` de la clase `Coordinate`, aparte, en el método `__hash__` tienes `return hash((self.__row, self.__column))`, pero `self.__row` y `self.__column` no existen, en todo caso deberían ser `self.row` y `self.column`. Si tienes `Board` y `Game` en archivos separados, falta importar `Coordiante` en Board y en Game falta importar `Board` y `Coordinate`, si estas clases están en el mismo modulo solo faltaría importar `Coordinate`.

Comment: Dicho esto,  esos problemas no justifican llo que dices que te pasa,  siempre y cuando estes importando y usando la misma clase `Coordinate` tanto en `Game` como en `Board`...

Comment: Todo corregido, pero te dejo el código de mi github, será mucho mas simple y se que te va a parecer muy raro el problema. [enlace](https://github.com/pcarroza/tictactoe-python/tree/dev)

Comment: Curioso ¿Como y desde donde estas ejecutando Game.py (en el codigo de git)? Le he echado un vistazo rápido y ejecutando Game.py la salida es `[Coordinate(1, 1), Coordinate(1, 2), Coordinate(1, 3)]
True
False
[Coordinate(1, 1), Coordinate(1, 2), Coordinate(1, 3)]`
...

Comment: Estimado gracias por tu tiempo. Ya descubrí el problema. Explico: El problema radica en la importación de los módulos yo tenía los siguientes: `from python.models.Coordinate import Coordinate` y lo correcto es `from src.main.python.models.Coordinate import Coordinate`. El error estriba en el nombre de la ruta. Esta era la razón por lo cual no importaba la clase `Board` en la clase `Game`. Gracias de todas forma estimado. Saludos fraternos.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, gracias por tu tiempo. He descubierto el problema y me gustaría explicarlo. El problema radica en la importación de los módulos. Originalmente tenía las siguientes líneas de importación: `from python.models.Coordinate import Coordinate`, pero lo correcto es `from src.main.python.models.Coordinate import Coordinate`. El error radica en la ruta del nombre. Esta es la razón por la cual no se importaba la clase `Board` en la clase `Game`.

Hay que poner atención en la importación automática de los módulos en pycharm.